# Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: (The system cannot find the file specified) when asking for file path

Tags: java, csv, file, input, filestream

I have a java program where I need to ask a user for an input of a csv file path in their computer, which it should then ask for a specific string within the file, search for that, and then print out all rows with that string.

The program works just fine when I hardcode the file path into a String like `String path = "C:\Users\Shinky\IdeaProjects\Enumeration\src\Salmon.csv"`, but once I manually enter the file path I get: Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: java.io.FileInputStream@1b6d3586 (The system cannot find the file specified)

I've tried storing the file directly underneath my project and also in the src folder, but I get the same Error every time. At this point I don't know what to do or if it would be easier to ask for a file path outside my IDE in general, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
import java.io.*;

public class StageReport {

    private static StageReport run;         //StageReport object
    private static FileInputStream path;    //Object path for csv file
    private Stage stage;                    //Object stage
    private static String choice;           //String choice for input
    private static String file;             //String inFile for csv file path input

    /**
     * constructor
     */
    public StageReport(Stage stage){
        this.stage = stage;
    }//end StageReport


    /**
     * finds and outputs correct mortality rates of fish
     */
    public void reader() throws Exception{

        //String path = "C:\\Users\\Shinky\\Desktop\\Salmon.csv";
        String line;

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(String.valueOf(path)));//BufferedReader reads csv file

        //switch for enum Stage class
        switch (stage) {
            case FISH:
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    String[] values = line.split(",");//csv file lines split from ,
                    //searches through file to find stages that correspond with user input and outputs correct year, stage and mortality rate
                    if(values[1].equalsIgnoreCase("Fish Entry")){
                        System.out.println(values[0]+" "+values[1]+" "+values[2]);
                    }

                }
                break;

            case GROW:
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    String[] values = line.split(",");//csv file lines split from ,
                    //searches through file to find stages that correspond with user input and outputs correct year, stage and mortality rate
                    if(values[1].equalsIgnoreCase("Grow-out")){
                        System.out.println(values[0]+" "+values[1]+" "+values[2]);
                    }

                }
                break;

            case HARVESTING:
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    String[] values = line.split(",");//csv file lines split from ,
                    //searches through file to find stages that correspond with user input and outputs correct year, stage and mortality rate
                    if(values[1].equalsIgnoreCase("Harvesting")){
                        System.out.println(values[0]+" "+values[1]+" "+values[2]);
                    }

                }

                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("No valid entries found");//prompt for no entries found in csv file
                break;
        }

    }//end reader

    /**
     * constructor
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));//BufferedReader declared
        System.out.print("Enter input file path and name: ");
        file = br.readLine();
        System.out.println("You entered: " + file);
        path = new FileInputStream(file);

        System.out.print("Enter the stage you would like to see: ");
        choice = br.readLine();


        //checks if user input matches enum Stage strings
        if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase(String.valueOf(Stage.FISH))) {
            run = new StageReport(Stage.FISH);
            run.reader();
        } else if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase(String.valueOf(Stage.GROW))) {
            run = new StageReport(Stage.GROW);
            run.reader();
        } else
            run = new StageReport(Stage.HARVESTING);
        run.reader();

    }//end main

}//end StageReport

enum Stage{ FISH("Fish Entry"), GROW("Grow-out"), HARVESTING("Harvesting");

    private String name;        //String name for enum names


    /**
     * Sets String names
     * @param name the names of the Strings in the enum classs
     */
    Stage(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }//end Stage

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }//end String

}//end Stage
```

Comment: try using forward slshes

Comment: I've tried both, unfortunately none work, even when I try single or double forward or backwards

Comment: A red flag seems to be `String.valueOf(path)` - is `path` not already a `String` ?

Comment: You are trying to use a FileInputStream as a file name. Look at your code -- the path that worked is a String, now you've changed path to a FileInputStream. Remove String.valueOf() and just pass path to the FileReader constructor.

Comment: Change `FileInputStream path` to `File path`, change `String.valueOf(path)` to just `path` and change `path = new FileInputStream(file)` to `path = new File(file)` in `main(String[] args)`

Comment: Thank you so so much, it finally works now. Could you explain to me though the difference between fileinputstream and just file though? I understand where I went wrong with everything else.

Comment: A File represents a named location in a filesystem, which may or may not exist. A FileInputStream is the sequence of bytes you receive when reading the data contained in a file (which obviously must actually exist).

Answer (score 1):

Try this, given file under src folder.

```
 InputStream stream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(file);
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));//BufferedReader 
 reads csv file
```